# How does this recursive code find original index?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I don't understand how it's returning the correct answer

```
    def bsearch(array, target)

      return nil if array.length == 0

      midpoint = array.length / 2
      case target <=> array[midpoint]
      when -1
        bsearch(array.take(midpoint), target)
      when 0
        midpoint
      when 1
        index = bsearch(array.drop(midpoint + 1), target)
        (index.nil?) ? nil : (midpoint + 1) + index
      end
    end


    p bsearch([1, 3, 4, 5, 9], 5) # => 3

    p bsearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 6) # => 5
```

Somehow it jumps from line 10 (where it should return midpoint ) to 13 where it somehow has the original array again?!

Here was my attempt but it fails by returning the midpoint of the last recursive version of the array

```
    def bsearch(array, target)

      return nil if array.length == 0
      aim = array.length / 2

      return nil if array.length == 1 && array[0] != target

     case target <=> array[aim]
     when 0
        aim
     when -1
      bsearch(array[0...aim], target)
     when 1
      bsearch(array[aim..-1], target)
     end
    end
```

Comment: "somehow it jumps from line 10 to line 13" - no, I don't think it does. More likely what you perceive as the "jump" is simply a return from the recursive call on line 12.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/128421. Your question is too broad. Explaining how code works isn't part of SO. If you're having a specific problem with the code you wrote then it would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between the code in question and your attempt is this line:

```
(index.nil?) ? nil : (midpoint + 1) + index
```

in the last branch. And it actually makes the difference.

The reason is that the algorithm "shrinks" the array on each miss, so the array you're looking in becomes smaller. But you still need the target index in the larger, original array. So, each time you take the "right" subarray and drop the "left" one you need to adjust the index somehow. And this is exactly what that line does.

Comment: I am able to notice the difference in the code but i cannot see how this line works to return an original midpoint